# How to filter regex in SQL developer

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have receive some kind of below regrex message with random set as below pattern. I want to filter this message by insert filter table in SQL developer how to make the pattern to filter out. Query to insert the filter is below.

```
37 35 32 41 44 44 37 36 32 46 34 34 34 45 45 34  42 31 31 34 31 41 36 43 39
44 37 41 35 45 35 39  20 44 61 74 65 54 69 6D 65 20 3A 20 53 75 6E 20  41 75 67 20 32 30
20 32 30 3A 30 37 3A 33 39 20  41 53 54 20 32 30 31 37 2C 20 65 72 72 6F 72 4D  65 73 73
61 67 65 20 3A 20 45 78 63 65 70 74 69  6F 6E 20 67 65 6E 65 72 61 74 65 64 20 6F 6E 20 
D9 A2 D9 A0 D9 A1 D9 A7 2D D9 A0 D9 A8 2D D9 A2  D9 A0 20 D9 A2 D9 A0 3A D9 A0 D9 A7 3A D9
A5 D9  A0 0A 0A 45 78 63 65 70 74 69 6F 6E 3A 20 6A 61  76 61 2E 6C



insert
into FILTER_IGNR (
  ID_ALARM_FILTER_IGNR,
  FILTER_PATTERN,
  CREATED_DATE_TIME,
  UPDATED_DATE_TIME,
  IS_ACTIVE)
select MAX(ID_ALARM_FILTER_IGNR)+1,
'.*ERROR.*', -- Check and change in this one
  sysdate,
  sysdate,
  1
from FILTER_IGNR
```

Comment: Please use the code formatting for the relevant parts (code and data), this way your spaces and indentation will be preserved. (an edit is apparently already in progress, couldn't do it myself). There is a button to help you do that, but all you need is put 4 spaces before each line of code.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't do regexes, it does patterns. They are not the same. Roughly: `_` => `.` and `%` => `.*` and `[a-z]`or `[^a-z]` the same but supports only simple characters.

Comment: You probably want `'%ERROR%'`.